# Is there any package or process to define required environment variables

Tags: node.js

I'm using .env files in my project and have process.env.VARIABLE_NAME dotted around the place. My .env files are not included in my git repo for obvious reasons. The only issue is its not clear to someone checking out the repo which environment variables are expected.

Is there any simple pre-made solution to this problem I am unaware of? How do others deal with this?

Maybe creating an environment.js file that exports all the process.env variables, that way everything is in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [config](https://npm.im/config) library handles this nicely, by combining config based on environments and hostnames with custom environment variable overrides/additions, which are all defined in one file. It's similar to your idea of re-exporting env vars all in one place, but also allows for combining with config values that aren't secret.

An example of how that works:

default.js:

```
const { name, version } = require('../package.json')
module.exports = {
  name,
  version,
  logLevel: 'debug',
}
```

custom-environment-variables.js:

```
module.exports = {
  logLevel: 'LOG_LEVEL',
}
```

production.js:

```
module.exports = {
  logLevel: 'info',
}
```

So `config.get('logLevel')` would return debug by default, info if NODE_ENV = production, or whatever process.env.LOG_LEVEL is if that's defined; and `name` and `version` would be the same across all environments.